# Creating a 2-Column Table Dynamically excluding certain values

Tags: arrays, excel, formula, vlookup

I'd consider myself okay at using Excel, but this seems to be well beyond my knowledge.

I need a formula to create a table like the one on the right, but I need it to be able to change whenever the values in the left table are changed.

I need something to compile a list of all the kinds of flowers that are used, but exclude any flowers that have a SUM of 0.

Example Image

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If one has the Dynamic Array formula FILTER() in Office 365, put this in the first cell:

```
=FILTER(CHOOSE({1,2},A:A,L:L),L:L>0)
```

[image]